# Rails.cache how to make increment and expiration at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I see that Redis doesn't allow make an `increment` and an `expiration` at the same time. I solved this doing it in 2 steps:

```
my_redis_client.incrby( key, amount )
my_redis_client.expire( key, expire_time )
```

But if I want to use `Rails.cache` I don't know how to obtain the same result in the most optimal way.

If I do this:

```
Rails.cache.increment( key, amount, :expires_in => expire_time )
```

The `expires_in` is completely ignored.

Is there any way to set an expiration time and execute an increment using `Rails.cache`?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like in Rails 6.0.0 the:

```
Rails.cache.increment( key, amount, :expires_in => expire_time )
```

works as expected:

- https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/9d5b02ec5062a23665ec596ef7d3efe4f5abcc27

Comment: This really helped me - I was finding if I didn't pass an `expires_in`, it would wipe out the value I'd previously set on the key via `fetch`, resulting in the key never expiring.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me in Rails 5.2

```
Rails.cache.write(key, 0, :raw => true, :unless_exist => true, :expires_in => expire_time)
Rails.cache.increment( key, amount )
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to monkeypatch `Rails.cache` ie

```
module CacheSupport
  def increment_with_ttl(key, amount, ttl)
    increment(key, amount)
    expire(key, ttl)
  end
end

Rails.cache.extend(CacheSupport)
```

Put this in `initializer` folder then you can start using `Rails.cache.increment_with_ttl()` in your project

Comment: I get the error `undefined method 'expire' for #<ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore:0X>`